# How can I get [nested] data from my JSON file in a database (mlab) using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, database, mlab

I know this question seems like it would obviously be answered somewhere, but I can't find it despite searching even the api.
My database looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "1234567890"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "Name": "Cow",
            "Type": "animal",
            "Type2": "",
        },
        {
            "Name": "Apricot, pack of 3",
            "Type": "animal",
            "Type2": "treetype",
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to do something like the user inputting "Apricot" and then it brings up "Apricot, pack of 3" and returns everything (name, type, type2)

So like (in awesome pseudocode)

```
var x= askuser
data = jsonarray(data)
arrayhandle = search(data(x))
console.print(arrayhandle.Name)
console.print(arrayhandle.Type)
console.print(arrayhandle.Type2)
```

Also I know it may be too much to ask (even breaching on fuzzy search), but I would really like it if my users could ask something like "Turkey" and the program respond will all the information for something named "Turkey, count 2"
Or if there were two entries that started with turkey, return all of them. So like the user inputs "turkey" and the name→desc is returned for "Turkey, count of 2" and "Turkey, count of 1/2" and "Turkey, pack of 20".

That would be perfect. But right now I just need to get the data. Also, it's sitting in mlab right now so I need to find a way to grab it from there and move it into my javascript file in glitch.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: edited to make shorter